# How do I generate a graph from Arduino sensor data?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors

I used a DHT 11 sensor with an Arduino Uno to measure temperature and humidity. I used the following code to print the temperature and relative humidity in Serial Monitor.

```
dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 7

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(DHT.temperature);
  Serial.print(" , ");
  Serial.println(DHT.humidity);
  delay(1000);
}
```

The Serial monitor printed the following data values in a list in the order of: time, temperature (Celsius), humidity (percentage).

```
22:17:55.686 -> 25.00 , 55.00
22:17:57.713 -> 25.00 , 55.00
22:17:59.741 -> 25.00 , 54.00
22:18:01.769 -> 25.00 , 54.00
22:18:03.793 -> 25.00 , 55.00
22:18:05.813 -> 25.00 , 54.00
22:18:07.837 -> 25.00 , 54.00
22:18:09.868 -> 25.00 , 55.00
22:18:11.880 -> 25.00 , 55.00
22:18:13.900 -> 25.00 , 55.00
22:18:15.915 -> 25.00 , 56.00
22:18:17.950 -> 25.00 , 56.00
22:18:19.972 -> 25.00 , 56.00
22:18:21.994 -> 25.00 , 56.00
22:18:24.024 -> 25.00 , 56.00
22:18:26.043 -> 25.00 , 56.00
22:18:28.093 -> 25.00 , 55.00
22:18:30.122 -> 25.00 , 55.00
22:18:32.141 -> 25.00 , 55.00
22:18:34.142 -> 25.00 , 55.00
```

I used the PuTTY software to save the sensor data to a CSV file. However, I end up with a few strange numbers at the top before the values start printing properly.

```
25.25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
25.00 , 53.00
```

Also, when I open the CSV file in Excel, the time values have disappeared, even though they were there in the serial monitor.
[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

What can I do to get the time stamps to show up in my spreadsheet? Additionally, is there a way I can have the graph automatically update as more data is read?

Comment: Your post title is how to generate the graph, but what you actually described  and asking is how to get ride the unnecessary garbage from the Putty.

Comment: The time stamps you see in the serial monitor are generated by the serial monitor.

Comment: You could write a visualization with processing

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the built-in Arduino Serial Plotter is all you need to visualize your data.  I wrote a [tutorial](https://www.woolseyworkshop.com/2019/05/03/using-the-arduino-serial-plotter-to-visualize-real-time-data/) a while back that might help you.

Comment: I  used the serial plotter. I get a plot of both temperature (as a blue line) and humidity (as a red line). However, I can't still get time to display on the x-axis. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I believe the x-axis is the number of samples.  If you send your plot values on a particular time cadence, the x-axis should then correspond to time.